# How to map keys to values for an individual field in a MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, mapping, case

Supposing we have a field status (`0` for disabled, `1` for enabled), and we need to get the literal values directly using MySQL, in other words: if we requested the query:

```
select status 
from `<table>`
```

We need the column to appear like this:

```
  status
----------
 disabled
 enabled
```

not as following:

```
 status
--------
   0
   1
```

Knowing that we don't have a mysql status table to join with and get the values as usual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would use a case statement, such as this:

```
select (case when status = 0 then 'disabled'
             when status = 1 then 'enabled'
        end)
from . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`if`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) control flow function (*as your `status` field can take only two values – [0,1]*):

```
select if(status = 0, 'disabled', 'enabled')
from <...>
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick to get value from a set by index

SELECT MAKE_SET(POWER(2,SomeIndexValue),'Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five');